# How to wait after reading from standard input?

Tags: bash

If I do something like
`cat myfile | myreader`

cat will send the *myfile* contents line by line, as fast as possible to standard output.

**I'd like to send the file contents line by line, but "sleep" some time after every line.**

Does any of you know how this can be done?

I know it's possible to wait in *myreader* but this is not the question. It's not always possible to modify the program reading standard input or it is not desirable in my case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this:

```
$ cat myfile|while read line; do echo $line; sleep 1; done|./myreader
```

Comment: or just `cat myfile | while read -r; do echo "$REPLY"; sleep 1; done | myreader`. Or better yet: `while read -r; do echo "$REPLY"; sleep 1; done < myfile | myreader` so as to avoid a useless use of cat.

Answer (score 0):

you could let awk insert a pause between lines:

```
cat myfile | awk '{print $0;system("sleep 2")}' | myreader
```

or better yet (to avoid UUOC):

```
awk '{print $0;system("sleep 2")}' myfile | myreader
```

Answer (score 0):

This could be done with:

```
while read line
do
    echo "$line"
done <<< myfile | ./myreader
```

But, why would you want that to happen? Smells like you want to use [`script`](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?script) or something like that.